# Security of receiving RSA-PSS computed mask in verification step

Tags: rsa, rsa-pss

I'm trying to verify an RSA-PSS padding in an Ethereum smart contract

The code to compute the MGF step (i.e. calculating many SHA1 hashes) is very expensive in terms of computation costs (gas) on Ethereum.

How insecure would it be to receive the MGF calculation result as input, and just verify parts of it by calculating just a few hashes from the MGF step and verify they match the input?

For example lets say the mask to be computed requires concatenating 40 hashes in MGF
we calculate just x of them and verify they are in the mask received as input.

The rest of the verification steps will be done as usual

Comment: I don't understand how MGF1-SHA-1 can become "very expensive". We are talking in the order of 13 SHA-1 rounds for RSA-2048. Isn't that less than the modexp in RSA.? 40 would be RSA-6400.